# How to configure pom to run SoapUI project from java

Tags: soapui

I need to run a project created from SoapUI though **Java**. By googling a bit I found the following solution, which works (but for version 4.5.0)

```
....
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>eviware</id>
<url>http://www.eviware.com/repository/maven2/</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>eviware</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
....
```

But now when i run it from java i get the following error

> [WsdlProject] Project 'ABCD - LOCAL' is from a newer version (5.0.0)
>   of soapUI than this (4.5.0) and parts of it may be incompatible or
>   incorrect. Saving this project with this version of soapUI may cause
>   it to function differently.

But I coulden't find the 5.0.0 version for "eviware". Can any one suggest me the new repository settings and dependency settings in order to run this in version 5.0.0+

Answer (score 3):

If all else fails, try the [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/maven-2x.html#1-basic-configuration):

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <projectFile>simple-test-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
            <projectProperties>
                <value>message=Hello World!</value>
            </projectProperties>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

So I guess for your dependency it would be:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: But the dependency could not be  found in the plugin repository. So it ask me to add a repository where I can find this dependency :(

Comment: What dependency are you talking about?

Comment: When I  add the dependency specified "com.smartbear.soapui", then eclipse says could not find dependency and add repository. I think the plugin repository do not know anything about the dependency you have given

Comment: I assumed you know what you're doing, my bad. :( I added the code for dependency repository, which is different from plugin repository.